# reactjs get the children count of an element

Tags: reactjs

im trying to get the count of child elements inside the 'container' div.

```js
let ElementRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        let Elementcount = ElementRef.childNodes.length
        console.log(Elementcount)
    })
    
    return (
       <div className='container' ref={ElementRef}>
         <p>paragraph one</p>
         <p>paragraph two</p>
         <p>paragraph three</p>
       </div>
    )
```

desired outcome in the console:

```
3
```

but im getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.current` property to access your `ref`.

`useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue)

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const ElementRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
      const Elementcount = ElementRef.current.childNodes.length
      console.log(Elementcount)
  })

  return (
     <div className='container' ref={ElementRef}>
       <p>paragraph one</p>
       <p>paragraph two</p>
       <p>paragraph three</p>
     </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define a useRef, you must use .current to get the current value. Change the code as follows

```
let ElementRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    let Elementcount = ElementRef.current.childNodes.length;
    console.log(Elementcount)
});
  return (
    <div className='container' ref={ElementRef}>
         <p>paragraph one</p>
         <p>paragraph two</p>
         <p>paragraph three</p>
       </div>
  );
```